# pymongo count() in for loop

Tags: python, pymongo

The following code:

```
client = MongoClient()
data_base = client.hkpr_restore

collection_list = ['agents', 'email_logs', 'property', 'user']
print data_base.agents.count()
print data_base.email_logs.count()
print data_base.property.count()
print data_base.user.count()

for x in collection_list:
    print data_base.x.count()
```

prints the following:

```
Begin Main
6622
32067
4168
18066
0
0
0
0
End Main
```

Why isn't the loop working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables that way. That's getting the attribute on `data_base` called `x` every time - nothing to do with the loop's `x` variable. Instead, you need to use `getattr`:

```
for x in collection_list:
    print getattr(data_base, x).count()
```

`getattr` allows you to dynamically refer to an attribute where the attribute's name is stored in a variable at not known until runtime.